# How to permanently stop audio in iOS with pressing home button?

Tags: ios, audio, delegates

I've got an application with a navigation tree. Somewhere there is an audio player with an mp3.

```
UITabViewController // controlled by AppDelegate.m
    -> UINavigationController
        -> UITableViewController // controlled by TableViewController.m
            -> UIViewController // with my AVAudioPlayer controlled by AudioViewController.m
```

In `AudioViewController.m` I have all my audio engine so i play/pause/stop it, and even kill it when pressing back button (using viewWillDisappear etc) - it plays only in this one view, not another, and it's good.

However there is an issue when i press home button while playback is on. It stops, but after going back to my app, it plays again from remembered time stamp.

I tried all this:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [self audioStop:self];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self audioStop:self];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self audioStop:self];
}

- (void)viewWillUnload
{
    [self audioStop:self];
    [super viewWillUnload];
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self audioStop:self];
}
```

But nothing happens.

Now i know that to manage if home button was pressed, i need to use `applicationWillResignActive` method from AppDelegate, but i have totally no idea how do i stop my audioplayer from here. I'm quite new to iOS and i'm not familiar with how `delegates` work, so please help me work this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let you  AppDelegate hold a reference for you UIViewcontroller some how and call it. Make sense?

```
   AppDelegate
        |
        v
    TableViewController (@property)
        |
        v
    UIViewController (@property)
        |
        v
    AudioPlayer (@property) --> [ stop];
```

Edit:

```
@interface TableViewController : UIViewController
{
     AudioPlayer * audioPlayer;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) AudioPlayer * audioPlayer;
... // other stuff
@end

@implementation TableViewController
@synthesize audioPlayer;
... // other stuff
@end
```

This way you can access the audio player from TableViewController object. If you hold TableViewController object this way it should be easy for you.

```
[tableViewController.audioPlayer someMethod];
```

something like that ..

Comment: Fell like dumb... a property of what?

Comment: Let your AppDelegate hold the TableViewController object as a class member. Create a property for UIViewController in your TableViewController. Similarly have a property in UIViewController for AudioPlayer. This way you can access it through tableViewController object. Get it?

Answer (score 0):

When home button was pressed, you need to use applicationWillResignActive method from AppDelegate, How we can use this method , i will show you. You need to use NotificationObeserver in your view controller.

**How To add NotificationOberserver**

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.application_resign_active(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
```

Now You can stop sound in this function : Like This

```
func application_resign_active(notification : NSNotification)
{

    if my_audio_player.isPlaying{
        print("Stop")
        my_audio_player.stop()
    }

}
```

my_audio_player is an instance of AudioPlayer

`var my_audio_player = AVAudioPlayer()`

You can also Check My Video , how i do this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxmhTAd1SU4